# Building Vice on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compiling, gcc, bashrc

I downloaded the Vice tar.gz, and followed the instructions here, including installing all the packages in the Debian list: https://www.lyonlabs.org/commodore/building-vice-on-linux.html

It said: configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.

So I installed GCC 8.2 per the instructions here: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/
and I still get the same error.  I have edited the .bashrc file and restarted but still to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Two moments here:

1. VICE is packaged for all Ubuntu releases - see [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=vice) - on 18.04 LTS you will get 3.1.0.dfsg1-1 version from *multiverse* pocket. So you can simply install it with:

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
    sudo apt install vice
   ```
2. You can compile newer 3.3 version of VICE if you install all needed dependencies with APT by following [installation instruction](https://www.lyonlabs.org/commodore/building-vice-on-linux.html):

   ```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential bison flex libnet1 libnet1-dev \
    libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev libgtk-3-dev libvte-dev libasound2-dev xa65 \
    libglew-dev texinfo
   ```

   And finally install it to the system with [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package):

   ```
    ./configure --enable-native-gtk3ui --with-alsa --enable-ethernet
    make -j3

    sudo apt install checkinstall
    sudo checkinstall make install
   ```